# Delegate Func as a property

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, .net-4.0, func

How can I pass e.g 2 strings to Func and return a string?
Let say I would like to pass FirstName and LastName and the result should be like FirstName + LastName;

Moreover, I would like to have a Func declared as a property.

Please take a look at my code:

```
public class FuncClass
{
    private string FirstName = "John";
    private string LastName = "Smith";
    //TODO: declare FuncModel and pass FirstName and LastName.
}

public class FuncModel
{
    public Func<string, string> FunctTest { get; set; }
}
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: `Func<string, string, string>` is not a "problem".

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean or what you've tried. A `Func<string, string>` doesn't take two strings, it takes a single string - and it's really unclear where `FirstName` and `LastName` would come in here. You could create a `Func<string>` that returned `FirstName + " " + LastName`, but that's not the same thing at all, as it has no inputs.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would like to have a Func as a property in FuncModel and write a body in FuncClass.

Comment: And that much is entirely feasible - but "declare FuncModel and pass FirstName and LastName" make no sense, nor can we tell what the func is really meant to *do*. What do you want it to return if I call `model.FunctTest("unclear")` for example?

Comment: `Func<string, string, string> FullName = (first, last) => first + last;` Usage: `FullName(FirstName, LastName)` Pretty much the same as how you would do delegates just more fancy.

Comment: @Cieja - Why are you doing this? What's the underlying problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
public class FuncModel
{
    //Func syntax goes <input1, input2,...., output>
    public Func<string, string, string> FunctTest { get; set; }
}

var funcModel = new FuncModel();
funcModel.FunctTest = (firstName, lastName) => firstName + lastName;
Console.WriteLine(funcModel.FuncTest("John", "Smith"));
```